# How to apply black and white filter on image using BufferedImageOp?

Tags: java, image, swing, image-processing, filter

I do have this code to increase the sharpness of the image using `BufferedImageOp`

```
class DecreaseSharpenFilter implements MyFilter{
    public BufferedImage processImage(BufferedImage image) {
        float[] decreaseSharpnessMatrix = {0.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, +1.0f , -5.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f };
         BufferedImageOp DecreaseSharpenFilter = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, decreaseSharpnessMatrix),
                    ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
                return DecreaseSharpenFilter.filter(image, null);
    }
}
```

Now I want to convert image to black and white by doing modifications to these lines but I don't really know what values to use in the matrix and how to convolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make a colorspace, then pass it in to your convertOP

```
ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);  
ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(cs, null);
BufferedImage image = op.filter(image, null);
```

Comment: Can you also please tell me how to adjust contrast and crop the image using the same above lines?

Comment: Cropping can use BufferedImages built in getSubimage(x,y,w,h) function.

Contrast control is a bit trickier, so look at this guys approach and try tinkering with it. http://gihansblog.com/2011/07/11/contrast-control-with-java-buffered-image-class/